# Can shell arguments be enclosed in characters *other* than single and double-quotes?

Tags: shell, arguments, escape-characters

I have a script that takes a MySQL SELECT query as its sole argument. Typically I enclose that query in single quotes and use double quotes within the query for enclosing the strings that are arguments of the query itself.

Occasionally this presents a problem, usually when the query itself must search for quote characters (single or double). I'm sure this can be resolved by properly escaping the single and double-quotes, but this is tricky since MySQL and the Linux shell may use different methods for escaping.

---

**Example...** here's an example, and it seems incredibly difficult to me... it needs to find single-quote characters that are preceded by a backslash. Note, this example does not intend to escape any characters for either MySQL or the CLI. The percent symbols act as wildcards in MySQL.

`` ./show-results 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE "%\'%"' ``

---

**Is it possible to use something other than single or double-quotes to enclose a shell argument?**

Comment: There exists in Bash an ANSI-C Quoting syntax `$'whatever'` with some designated escapes. Not sure how convenient that might be for the average user. It might be simpler to use a Here Document instead of a command arg, as this will be treated as data without expansions.

Comment: and single quotes can be escaped in an ANSI-C string: `echo $'don\'t do it'`. But here documents avoid the leaning toothpick syndrome.

Comment: Are you looking for a portable solution or are shell-specific alternatives fine as well?

Comment: Also, and more importantly, does your use case involve interactively typing queries on the command line or writing them down as part of some script in which `./show-results` is invoked?

Answer (score 4):

You did not provide a sample so I'm not sure if this will work for you.

Use here documents:

```
echo "$(cat <<'EOF'
foo "x" bar 'x'
EOF
)"
```

When you run this with `set -x` you'll see that bash will escape this for you:

```
+ echo 'foo "x" bar '\''x'\'''
foo "x" bar 'x'
```

---

Now with your sample:

```
./show-results "$(cat <<'EOF'
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE "%\'%"
EOF
)"
```

Results in the correct escaped arg:

```
./show-results 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE "%\'\''%"'
```

The first backslash is inside `''` so it is not acting as an escape and results in `\`, the second one is outside `''` and is used to escape the single `'`.

Comment: And the heredoc labels must appear on their own lines like other languages?

Comment: @AaronCicali Yes, the content of the here-document starts on the line that follows `<<label` and is terminated by a line containing only `label`.